# Excel File Upload in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, import

For one of the application I need to upload excel file .The excel file is generated by another application. when I upload the excel file I am getting error message.

**Error**

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): External table is not in the expected format. at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)" .

I check all the possible scenario to resolve this issue. one thing I notice when I upload the same excel file save as with Excel 97, 2000 format its work.
On the other hand I checked file encoding `Encoding in UCS-2 Little Endian`  and encoding of save as new excel file(97,2000 format) it's showing "ANSI".

I am unable to figure out what is the issue .

Comment: Probably the generated excel file is not an xls file, that must be a binary file, but it is a csv file with xls extension.